# Application stops when the user lock the phone - IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

in my application user can upload a file, but if he lock his phone, it stops uploading. Is there any way to upload or download when the phone is locked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. Apple does not want iOS apps to run in the background as they might drain the battery.

But Apple has added many APIs so iOS can take over the background task on behalf of the app. And uploading and downloading is one of these tasks.

Have a look at [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession) and in particular at [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1407496-backgroundsessionconfigurationwi?language=objc). This is how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

So with the way iOS works, Apple pauses background applications when the device is locked. You'll have to use specific API calls to allow your app to continue working in background, such as beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler